# Iterate an array of class in Promise written using TypeScript and TypeCast Generics

Tags: typescript, es6-promise

I have the below code in OO.ts file :

```js
import * as $ from "jquery";
        interface ValidatableInterface {
    isValid() : boolean;
}

class User implements ValidatableInterface {
    /*public name: string;
    public password: string;*/

    constructor(public name:string, public password:string) {
    }

    getString() {
        return `${this.name} -> ${this.password}`;
    }

    isValid() : boolean {
        return true;
    }
}

        class GenericRepository<T extends ValidatableInterface> {
    private _url : string;
    constructor(url : string) {
        this._url = url;
    }

    public getAsync() {
        return new Promise((resolve: (entities: T[]) => void, reject) => {
            $.ajax({
                url: this._url,
                type: "GET",
                dataType: "json",
                success: (data) => {
                    let list : T[];
                    let items = <T[]>data.items;
                    for(let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
                        if(<T><any>items[i].isValid()) {
                            list.push(items[i]);
                        }
                    }
                    resolve(list);
                },
                error: (e) => {
                    reject(e);
                }
            })
        })
    }
}

        export {
        User,
        GenericRepository
        }
```

In app.ts i am have the below code:

```js
import { User, GenericRepository } from './OO';

let userRepository = new GenericRepository<User>('./shared/users.json');
userRepository.getAsync()
    .then((users: User[])=> {
        console.log(`User Repository =>`);
        /*
        Not working either
        users.forEach(function(user) {
            console.log(user.getString());
        });*/
        for(let i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
            console.log(users[i].getString());
        }
    });
```

When I try to iterate the user array (Array of user class) the error I am seeing is Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: e[t].getString is not a function and In the forEach the error I am seeing is Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: e.getString is not a function.

I am unable to typecast : The error I am now getting is Uncaught TypeError: n[r].isValid is not a function

Can anybody explain what is this error.

Thanks in advance

Comment: typescript will not transform the incoming json from the server to a class just because you added the type there. The type is only informative, you'll have to create new instances of that class yourself.

Comment: Thanks I will try.

Comment: Hi I tried this ```users.forEach(function(user) {
            let u = new User(user.name, user.password);
            console.log(u.getString());
        });```. Still getting the same error. Is this the correct way.

Comment: the way you have it written the name and password are not setable in a constructor. you can change the constructor to `constructor(public name, public password)`

Comment: Sorry I did not update my question. I did perform that change and now i used normal for loop like ```for(let i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
            let u = new User(users[i].name, users[i].password);
            console.log(u.getString());
        }```. I am able to print. But in forEach same error

Comment: are you sure the server returns the list of users? have you tried debugging/logging the value returned by the server?

Comment: It's working in both ways. Sorry may be my gulp build took some time so I saw the same error.

Comment: Yes it is returning list of users. Thanks for the explaining the error :)

Comment: Hi @toskv. I have updated my question and I am trying to use Generics. But The error I am getting now is ```Uncaught TypeError: n[r].isValid is not a function```. I tried this too ``` if((<T><any>items[i]).isValid()) {
                            list.push(items[i]);
                        }```
Could you help me out here

Comment: you have to either limit the type of T to User (or a common interface) or not implement that part in the generic service but in the specific part of the code that's calling it.

Comment: I will try. But generally if I want to TypeCast Generics is it possible?

Comment: there is no type casing in typescript, only type assertion. there is no casting at all in typescript.

Comment: But generally if I want to TypeCast Generics is it possible?  -> Dumb Questions sorry :P

Comment: you can assert that a type is a generic type. But at runtime it will not transform the object into another type of object. it's just for compile time checks.

Comment: I am studying TypeScript Modern Development book and the author used this as an example for Generic Constraints. Seems to work in that example. Maybe  he is using older version of TypeScript. I will check. Thanks :)

Comment: in your case since T already extends ValidatableInterface you shouldn't need `<T><any>` at all.

Comment: Yes I tried without specifying <T><any>. But got error n[r].isValid is not a function